# How to change time like 23:59:59 in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, datetime, ecmascript-6

I want to make to time like 23:59:59. Now it's printing 05 2022 00:00:00 and my requirement is Sat Nov 05 2022 23:59:59.

```
var now = new Date();
var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
var lastSunday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-today.getDay()));

var from = new Date(lastSunday.getTime() - (7*24*60*60*1000));
var to = new Date(lastSunday.getTime() - (1*24*60*60*1000));
```

Output:

```
console.log(now.toString()) //today Thu Nov 10 2022 13:20:22 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
console.log(from.toString()) // Sun Oct 30 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
console.log(to.toString()) //Sat Nov 05 2022 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

Comment: If you want a custom date format. Checkout https://momentjs.com/

Comment: @MyatMinSoe Thanks , but I tried .. not getting success , I have to just change the time . could you please help

Comment: You would have to store date using state variable like `const [date,setDate]` and then maybe make an interval that would run every x milliseconds, updating date in every tick.

Comment: wait if you simply need to specify a date, you can use the Date constructor. If needed, it can specify the date down to the millisecond https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date#syntax

Comment: @MyatMinSoe Please don't recommend MomentJS [the project is officially dead](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hope this will help you!!

```js
const myFunction = () => {
  var now = new Date();
  var today = new Date(now.getFullYear(), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
  var lastSunday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate() - today.getDay()));

  var temp = new Date(lastSunday.getTime() - 1000);
  document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = temp;
};
```

```html
 <body onload="myFunction()">
 <h1 id="temp"></h1>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks .. it is correct but it is reducing the date also  in my code it is becoming 4th Nov

Comment: It halped .. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think really quickly it's possible to use setHours :

> var lastSunday = new Date(today.setDate(today.getDate()-today.getDay()));
> lastSunday.setHours(23,59,59,999);

And you're done